# How can I view new rows in DataGridView added to list that is previously assigned as datagridview.datasource?

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I view new rows in datagridview added to list that is previously assigned as datagridview.datasource?

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-call the databind() method to see any updates to the data.

Comment: i have this code to data grid view 
list<businessEntity.group> groupList;
DataGridView1.DataSource = groupList;
how i will write databind()??!!
please......explain ......

Comment: DataGridView1.DataBind(); - simple as that

Comment: `DataBind` **method** is for Web based Application and `DataSource` **property** is for Windows based applications.

Answer (score 2):

On WinForms:

If the list doesn't automatically notify the `DataGridView` of changes, the only way I know to display the new rows is to set the `DataSource` to `null` and then back to your list again.

You should probably be using a `BindingSource` here to both make your life easier and avoid visual hiccups in the UI. Bind the `DataGridView` to the `BindingSource` and the `BindingSource` to your list. Then you can just call `BindingSource.ResetBindings(false)` to update it with your new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Hey It depends on what way you are using to assign data to Datagridview.

If you are using Datagridview.datasource then you just need to add rows to the table assigned to that datagridview.

Thanks